# Error: invalid BigNumber value (argument="value", value=undefined, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.6.2)

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I was doing the Patrick Collins tutorial and [link](https://youtu.be/gyMwXuJrbJQ?t=55180) got this error `Error: invalid BigNumber value (argument="value", value=undefined, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.6.2)` when I was running `hh deploy`
I got this error for the 01.deploy-raffle.js.

01.deploy-raffle.js code:

```
const { network, ethers } = require("hardhat")
const { developmentChains, networkConfig } = require("../helper-hardhat-config")
const { verify } = require("../utils/verify")

const VRF_SUB_FUND_AMOUNT = ethers.utils.parseEther("30")

module.exports = async function ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) {
    const { deploy, log } = deployments
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()
    const chainId = network.config.chainId
    let vrfCoordinatorV2Adress, subscriptionId

    if (developmentChains.includes(network.name)) {
        const vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContract("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock")
        vrfCoordinatorV2Adress = vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.address
        const transactionResponse = await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.createSubscription()
        const transactionRecipt = await transactionResponse.wait(1)
        subscriptionId = transactionRecipt.events[0].args.subId
        await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.fundSubscription(subscriptionId, VRF_SUB_FUND_AMOUNT)
    } else {
        vrfCoordinatorV2Adress = networkConfig[chainId]["vrfCoordinatorV2"]
        subscriptionId = networkConfig[chainId]["subscriptionId"]
    }

    const entranceFee = networkConfig[chainId]["entranceFee"]
    const gasLane = networkConfig[chainId]["gasLane"]
    const callbackGasLimit = networkConfig[chainId]["callbackGasLimit"]
    const interval = networkConfig[chainId]["interval"]

    const args = [
        vrfCoordinatorV2Adress,
        entranceFee,
        gasLane,
        subscriptionId,
        callbackGasLimit,
        interval,
    ]
    const raffle = await deploy("Raffle", {
        from: deployer,
        args: args,
        log: true,
        waitConfirmation: network.config.blockConfirmation || 1,
    })

    if (!developmentChains.includes(network.name) && process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY) {
        log("Verifying...")
        await verify(raffle.address, args)
    }
    log("------------------------------------------------------------")
}

module.exports.tags = ["all", "raffle"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to see if the keys in the networkConfig object in the helper-hardhat-config.js file match the argument array you set up in 01-deploy-raffle.js.

```
const args = [
        vrfCoordinatorV2Adress,
        entranceFee,
        gasLane,
        subscriptionId,
        callbackGasLimit,
        interval,
```

If you have copied and pasted the helper-hardhat-config.js file like I did, the networkConfig object will have different keys.

```
31337: {
        name: "localhost",
        subscriptionId: "588",
        gasLane: "0xd89b2bf150e3b9e13446986e571fb9cab24b13cea0a43ea20a6049a85cc807cc", // 30 gwei
        keepersUpdateInterval: "30",
        raffleEntranceFee: "100000000000000000", // 0.1 ETH
        callbackGasLimit: "500000", // 500,000 gas
    },
```

Making these adjustments to either of the scripts fixed the issue for me.

Best of luck!

Comment: Fixing the argument array fixed my problem. I appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and needed to change `keepersUpdateInterval` to `interval` and `raffleEntranceFee` to `entranceFee`

It also helped adding `console.log(args)` to my code to see which were undefined which was causing the big number error.

Thanks for the help!